# ServerException was Unhandled

Tags: sharepoint, caml

Getting this error:
ServerException was Unhandled and when I fix my query I don't get the exact results when I filter it on SharePoint.

```
<View>
<Query>
<Where>
<And>
<And>
<Or>
<Or>
<Or>
<Eq><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Completed</Value></Eq>
<Eq><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Not yet submitted</Value></Eq>
</Or>
<Eq><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Completed</Value></Eq>
</Or>
<Eq><FieldRef Name='Approval_x0020_Month' /><Value Type='Text'>" + approvalmonth + "</Value></Eq>
</Or>
</And>
<Eq><FieldRef Name='PG_x0020_ID_x003a_Service_x0020_' /><Value Type='Lookup'>RPCS</Value></Eq>
<Eq><FieldRef Name='PG_x0020_ID_x003a_Service_x0020_' /><Value Type='Lookup'>PLM</Value></Eq>
</And>
</Where>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>
</Query>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing an And Tag.

Here is how it should be:

```
<View>
<Query>
<Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <And>
                <Or>
                    <Or>
                        <Or>
                        <Eq><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Completed</Value></Eq>
                        <Eq><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Not yet submitted</Value></Eq>
                        </Or>
                        <Eq><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Completed</Value></Eq>
                    </Or>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='Approval_x0020_Month' /><Value Type='Text'>" + approvalmonth + "</Value></Eq>
                </Or>
            </And>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='PG_x0020_ID_x003a_Service_x0020_' /><Value Type='Lookup'>RPCS</Value></Eq>
        </And>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='PG_x0020_ID_x003a_Service_x0020_' /><Value Type='Lookup'>PLM</Value></Eq>
    </And>
</Where>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>
</Query>
</View>
```